# Unable to Open folder in ubuntu20 via pyqt application

Tags: ubuntu, pyqt

I am working on an application, in which it is required to open file and folder where file is located. I am working in ubuntu20. I am developing this app using pyqt.

Till now, I have tried following to achieve my above requirements:

1. Tried to execute xdg-open command as:
   `os.system(f'xdg-open "{path}"')`
2. Tried using Qt's internal module QDesktopServices as:
   `QDesktopServices.openUrl(QUrl(path))`

But in both these approaches file index is opened in default web browser and file in opened inside browser. **I am unable to open corresponding folder in Ubuntu's file explorer and file using default applications.**

Although, I got over in case of opening a file with default application by executing whole path as a command: `os.system(path)`, but looking for a better/reliable solution.

**--------UPDATE---------**
when i execute `xdg-open path` in terminal folder is opened in file explorer and file gets opened using default application.

Comment: It seems more like an issue with user configuration (about which you can do very little). Does the same happen even if you run `xdg-open <path>` on a terminal?

Comment: thanx for the quick reply, folder gets opened in file explorer and file in default application.

Comment: I just noticed that you're using `QUrl(path)`, but for local files you should use `QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)`.

Comment: @musicamante also tried QUrl.fromLocalFile(path) but result is the same i.e. file index and file opens in browser

Comment: Are you completely sure that the path you're using is valid? Can you post it?

Comment: @musicamante yes definitely, i debugged my code, copied the value of path from it and pasted in terminal and got the desired result.

Comment: There's no guarantee that `xdg-open` will open a folder path in a file-manager. It depends on what applications have been configured to handle the inode/directory mimetype, and which one has been given priority by the user. It may work as expected on *your* system, but it's highly unlikely it will work the same way for all users (especially on linux). Probably the best compromise is to allow the user to specify the appropriate "open with" command themselves.

Comment: @josh as ekhumoro pointed out (better than I tried to explain in my first comment), it's all based on user (system) configuration. What puzzles me is that you're able to properly start the file manager or program from `xdg-open` but not from Qt. Are you using a virtualenv or running your program from an IDE? In that case, have you tried to run the program from the terminal?

Comment: Yes, and as previously requested, it could be ***very*** helpful to see the exact output of `print(repr(f'xdg-open "{path}"'))` and `print(QUrl.fromLocalFile(path))`.